# How to get the data being passed to router link in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a router sample below , now how will I get the details of that when it is done navigating on that page or when it reach the user page ?.

I wanted to check on my user.component.ts that the navigation comes from this   [routerLink]="['user', user.id, 'details']"

```
[routerLink]="['user', user.id, 'details']"
```

Comment: Do you want to get the value of `user.id` in `user.component.ts`? Add the code of routing module too.

Comment: If you pass the param correctly you can get that param using ActivatedRoute service in your component

Comment: Does this help? [Accessing Query Parameters](https://angular.io/guide/router#accessing-query-parameters-and-fragments)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to watch the route changes.

```
...
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
...
constructor(
    private router: Router
) {}
...
ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
        if(event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
             // Check if this.router.url is matching to the user page's url 
             // pattern
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
```

constructor(
private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute,
) {}

```
orderId: any;
...
ngOnInit() {
   this.activeRoute.url.subscribe((segments: UrlSegment[]) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < segments.length; i++) {
        this.orderId = segments[i];
      }
    });
}
```